# What is $\int\limits_0^tW(s)ds$ where $W$ is standard brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm learning Ito calculus and integrals with respect to BM are defined but what about integrals of stochastic processes (like BM itself) with respect to Lebesgue measure?

It is true that  $\int\limits_0^tW(s)ds=\lim\limits_{\Delta\rightarrow0}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m_\Delta}W(t_{j-1})(t_j-t_{j-1})$ where $0=j_0<j_1<\dots<j_m=t$ is a partition of $[0,t]$ with $\Delta=\min_j|t_j-t_{j-1}|$ but is it expressible as a stochastic process $(X(t))_{t\in[0,T]}$ in a cleaner way than above?

Comment: yes it's true (that this equality hold a.s.). But you can't express this integral in a nicer way.